# Package extension not working: Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, package

I have a module in Magento that I am creating a package extension. I am able to create a package extension successfully which is stored in `[magento]/var/connect` folder. I have the `package.xml,extension.xml` and `extension-0.0.0.0.1.tgz` files created.

However, when I untar the `extension-0.0.0.0.1.tgz`, it is empty. Also when I try to upload the extension through Magento connect I get the error as

> **CONNECT ERROR:** Package file is invalid. Empty package contents section

How can I create a package of my extension properly. Can anyone please help.
I have already gone through mane links but I am not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in adding the contents of the module while packaging the extension. Whenever we are creating a package of a custom module we need to make sure that we have added all of the module files in the contents section while packaging the extension.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that you are trying to upload the a folder that contains the package.xml. Make sure the package.xml is present in the top most directory level.

tar -cvzf extension_1.0.0.tgz *

when you expand it using the following command:
tar -xvf extension_1.0.0.tgz

the pakage.xml file should be present in the current folder where you decompressed the tgz file